# How to save pandas dataframe as a json file with a different name on each run

Tags: python, json, pandas

I want to run an algorthim I've made to create a .json file of a pandas dataframe, but since it is saving in the same file I have to change the name by hand everytime. How do I make it so that everytime I run the script it saves as a different name without me changing it by hand.

Here is how I've written it right now.

```
df2.to_json('Desktop/Thesis_Brainstorm/Thesis_Code/Office_Context/Office_15.json')
```

How I've tried to write it but hasn't worked.

```
TodaysDate = str(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %X")).replace(":", "")
run = 'rand_search_' + TodaysDate
df2.to_json('Desktop/Thesis_Brainstorm/Thesis_Code/Office_Context/' + run + '.json')
```

Was hoping it would save the output as a new name as to not override the previous run.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you:

```py
from datetime import datetime
file_name = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")+".json"
path = "Desktop/Thesis_Brainstorm/Thesis_Code/Office_Context/"
path+file_name

df2.to_json(path+file_name)
```

Note: you must to take care about you path. If it is not correctly set could throw an error.